# SVG shape hase extra height

Tags: html, svg

I have made this shape with inkskape

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   width="86.708229mm"
   height="108.46725mm"
   viewBox="0 0 86.708229 108.46725"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg5"
   inkscape:export-filename="bitmap.svg"
   inkscape:export-xdpi="96"
   inkscape:export-ydpi="96"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="namedview7"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#000000"
     borderopacity="0.25"
     inkscape:showpageshadow="2"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pagecheckerboard="0"
     inkscape:deskcolor="#d1d1d1"
     inkscape:document-units="mm"
     showgrid="false" />
  <defs
     id="defs2">
    <linearGradient
       inkscape:collect="always"
       id="linearGradient1332">
      <stop
         style="stop-color:#2ebdbe;stop-opacity:1;"
         offset="0"
         id="stop1330" />
      <stop
         style="stop-color:#bbfbf2;stop-opacity:1;"
         offset="1"
         id="stop1328" />
    </linearGradient>
    <inkscape:path-effect
       effect="fillet_chamfer"
       id="path-effect427"
       is_visible="true"
       lpeversion="1"
       nodesatellites_param="F,0,0,1,0,3.175,0,4 @ F,0,0,1,0,3.175,0,4 @ F,0,0,1,0,3.175,0,4 @ F,0,0,1,0,3.175,0,4 @ F,0,0,1,0,3.175,0,4 @ F,0,0,1,0,3.175,0,4"
       unit="px"
       method="auto"
       mode="F"
       radius="12"
       chamfer_steps="4"
       flexible="false"
       use_knot_distance="true"
       apply_no_radius="true"
       apply_with_radius="true"
       only_selected="false"
       hide_knots="false" />
    <linearGradient
       inkscape:collect="always"
       xlink:href="#linearGradient1332"
       id="linearGradient1338"
       x1="-8.7238359"
       y1="103.88622"
       x2="137.07281"
       y2="33.141083"
       gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
       gradientTransform="matrix(1.0169463,0,0,0.56544787,9.4308219,-0.08872541)" />
  </defs>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1"
     transform="translate(-60.976129,-17.450189)">
    <path
       id="path424"
       style="opacity:1;fill:url(#linearGradient1338);fill-opacity:1;stroke:#ffffff;stroke-width:1.00318;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;paint-order:normal"
       inkscape:transform-center-x="-2.7149655"
       inkscape:transform-center-y="0.12577677"
       d="M 74.631466,44.717104 62.421924,34.403638 a 2.6778389,2.6778389 90.043215 0 1 0.0031,-4.093976 L 74.671628,19.996493 a 8.6973678,8.6973678 159.95323 0 1 5.603571,-2.044714 l 48.153211,0.0067 a 8.6807368,8.6807368 20.098102 0 1 5.60047,2.049272 l 12.20963,10.313627 a 2.6778292,2.6778292 90.04357 0 1 -0.003,4.093967 l -12.24664,10.313026 a 8.6974755,8.6974755 159.95346 0 1 -5.60359,2.044695 l -48.153211,-0.0067 a 8.680796,8.680796 20.097976 0 1 -5.600483,-2.049262 z"
       sodipodi:nodetypes="ccccccc"
       inkscape:path-effect="#path-effect427"
       inkscape:original-d="M 77.056949,46.765923 59.996441,32.354819 77.100199,17.951336 l 54.503211,0.0076 17.06057,14.411285 -17.10382,14.403302 z"
       inkscape:export-filename=".\path424.svg"
       inkscape:export-xdpi="96"
       inkscape:export-ydpi="96" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

and the shape is ok But the overall height is so much more that the shape

in this picture I've opened it in browser and as you see the height is **409.95px**

that is not desirable

[image]

### how can I remove the extra height of that ?

just some bela bela to let me post this
just some bela bela to let me post this
just some bela bela to let me post this

Comment: the attribute width/height in the SVG tag force it to be that many millimeters and thus so many pixels - if you remove the attributes and view the SVG file in a browser it will take up the entire viewport dimensions .. either way the viewBox attribute needs to be precise too, or left out. Depending on your usage you may want to set width/height both to 100% and the viewBox to the SVG size of your drawing - reduce the canvas in your SVG editor (apparently Inkscape) before exporting to its minimal size.

Comment: Use this viewBox instead: `viewBox="0 0 86.7 29"` and delete the height attribute of the svg element

Comment: @enxaneta where the 29 come from ?

Comment: I'm wrapping the transformed group <g id="layer1" in a group and get the bounding box of this one with getBBox(). The result is `SVGRect {x: 0.49596405029296875, y: 0.5015888214111328, width: 85.71627807617188, height: 28.821285247802734}`  I'm rounding the value of the height property to the ceiling i.e 29. **Observation** getBBox of a transformed element would give you the bounding box before the transformation. This is why you need an other group whapping the transformed one.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the width and the height attributes from `<svg>` and alter the viewBox so that it matches the size of the content.

In this example I also removed the transform attribute from the `<g>` and replaced the path itself using the tool [SvgPathEditor](https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/).

Now the path takes up 100% of the box and the aspect ratio matches the content.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   viewBox="0 0 86 29"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg5"
   inkscape:export-filename="bitmap.svg"
   inkscape:export-xdpi="96"
   inkscape:export-ydpi="96"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="namedview7"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#000000"
     borderopacity="0.25"
     inkscape:showpageshadow="2"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pagecheckerboard="0"
     inkscape:deskcolor="#d1d1d1"
     inkscape:document-units="mm"
     showgrid="false" />
  <defs
     id="defs2">
    <linearGradient
       inkscape:collect="always"
       id="linearGradient1332">
      <stop
         style="stop-color:#2ebdbe;stop-opacity:1;"
         offset="0"
         id="stop1330" />
      <stop
         style="stop-color:#bbfbf2;stop-opacity:1;"
         offset="1"
         id="stop1328" />
    </linearGradient>
    <inkscape:path-effect
       effect="fillet_chamfer"
       id="path-effect427"
       is_visible="true"
       lpeversion="1"
       nodesatellites_param="F,0,0,1,0,3.175,0,4 @ F,0,0,1,0,3.175,0,4 @ F,0,0,1,0,3.175,0,4 @ F,0,0,1,0,3.175,0,4 @ F,0,0,1,0,3.175,0,4 @ F,0,0,1,0,3.175,0,4"
       unit="px"
       method="auto"
       mode="F"
       radius="12"
       chamfer_steps="4"
       flexible="false"
       use_knot_distance="true"
       apply_no_radius="true"
       apply_with_radius="true"
       only_selected="false"
       hide_knots="false" />
    <linearGradient
       inkscape:collect="always"
       xlink:href="#linearGradient1332"
       id="linearGradient1338"
       x1="-8.7238359"
       y1="103.88622"
       x2="137.07281"
       y2="33.141083"
       gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
       gradientTransform="matrix(1.0169463,0,0,0.56544787,9.4308219,-0.08872541)" />
  </defs>
  <g
     id="layer1">
    <path
       id="path424"
       style="opacity:1;fill:url(#linearGradient1338);fill-opacity:1;stroke:#ffffff;stroke-width:1.00318;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;paint-order:normal"
       d="M 13.2315 26.7653 L 1.0219 16.4518 a 2.6778 2.6778 90.0432 0 1 0.0031 -4.094 L 13.2716 2.0447 a 8.6974 8.6974 159.9532 0 1 5.6036 -2.0447 l 48.1532 0.0067 a 8.6807 8.6807 20.0981 0 1 5.6005 2.0493 l 12.2096 10.3136 a 2.6778 2.6778 90.0436 0 1 -0.003 4.094 l -12.2466 10.313 a 8.6975 8.6975 159.9535 0 1 -5.6036 2.0447 l -48.1532 -0.0067 a 8.6808 8.6808 20.098 0 1 -5.6005 -2.0493 z" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

the attribute width/height in the SVG tag force it to be that many millimeters and thus so many pixels - if you remove the attributes and view the SVG file in a browser it will take up the entire viewport dimensions .. either way the viewBox attribute needs to be precise too, or left out. Depending on your usage you may want to set width/height both to 100% and the viewBox to the SVG size of your drawing - reduce the canvas in your SVG editor (apparently Inkscape) before exporting to its minimal size.